# FTP on Windows through Mac server?

Tags: windows, mac, ftp

Is it possible to have files hosted on a windows computer that could then be FTPd over to a Mac's Lion server, and then to clients? The windows is pretty capable hardware-wise, as is the mac, I'm just wondering if I need any extra software or how I can find out how to do the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no shortage of both free and commercial FTP servers for Windows.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software

But if the goal is simply file sharing - you may want to consider simply [enabling Windows file sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Enable-file-and-printer-sharing) and then [configuring your Mac to connect to the Windows share](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568).